# .nextval JDBC insert problem

Tags: java, sql, oracle, jdbc, ora-01722

I try to insert into table with sequence .nextval as primary key, the sql in Java is

```
sql = "INSERT INTO USER 
         (USER_PK, ACCOUNTNUMBER, FIRSTNAME, LASTNAME, EMAIL ) 
       VALUES 
         (?,?,?,?,?)";
   ps = conn.prepareStatement(sql);
   ps.setString(1, "User.nextval");
   ps.setString(2, accountNumber);
   ps.setString(3, firstName);
   ps.setString(4, lastName);
   ps.setString(5, email);
```

However, the error is `ORA-01722: invalid number`

All the other fields are correct, I think it is the problem of sequence, is this correct?

Comment: Is this supposed to be 0 indexed?  Edit: no

Comment: Is the name of your sequence User?  It needs to be SequenceName.NextVal  Also, just use the prepared statement for everything BUT the sequencename.NextVal

Comment: I don't do Oracle, but in PostgreSQL they (the sequences which are created as `SERIAL PRIMARY KEY` type) are auto-incremented on every `INSERT`. You would usually like to omit it from the `INSERT` statement so that the DB will handle it itself. So, in your case, you'd likely omit `USER_PK` column from your SQL. MySQL, DB2 and SQLServer also has similar constructs.

Comment: @BalusC: SQL Server 2011 will support sequences - now just need to get MySQL to do it :/.  Oracle doesn't have anything similar to PostgreSQL's `serial` that I'm aware of.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The problem is that the first column is a numeric data type, but your prepared statement is submitting a string/VARCHAR data type.  The statement is run as-is, there's no opportunity for Oracle to convert your use of nextval to get the sequence value.

Here's an alternative via Java's PreparedStatement syntax:

```
sql = "INSERT INTO USER 
        (USER_PK, ACCOUNTNUMBER, FIRSTNAME, LASTNAME, EMAIL ) 
       VALUES 
        (user.nextval, ?, ?, ?, ?)";
ps = conn.prepareStatement(sql);
ps.setString(1, accountNumber);
ps.setString(2, firstName);
ps.setString(3, lastName);
ps.setString(4, email);
```

This assumes that `user` is an existing sequence -- change to suit.

Comment: Though personally, this would be an Oracle function if it were up to me.  Then the sequence reference would be in the function, just supply the same parameters for insertion.

Comment: Worked like a charm THANKS! :D