# I created a sequence for id and I need max id from the table. So, I am using autoGeneratedKeys() but its not working

Tags: java

I created a sequence for id and I need max id from the table. So, I am using `autoGeneratedKeys()`, but it's not working.

```
public int createDataDAOImplentation(UserData c){
    int i=0; String sql="";
    try
    {
        ds.setPs("insert into contact(id,firstName,lastName,email,dob,gender)values(contact_seq.nextval,?,?,?,?,?)");
        ds.getPs().setString(1, c.getFirstname());
        ds.getPs().setString(2, c.getLastName());
        ds.getPs().setString(3, c.getEmail());
        ds.getPs().setint(4, c.getDob());
        ds.getPs().setLong(5, c.getGender());
        ds.getPs().executeQuery();
        ResultSet rs = ds.getPs().getGeneratedKeys();
        System.out.println("iam");
        if(rs.next()){
            i = rs.getInt(1);
            System.out.println("in"0);
        }
        ds.getCon().commit();
        ds.getCon().close();
    }
    catch(SQLException ex)
}
```

[image]

Comment: You should show your code.

Comment: please share your code

Comment: @Jure  -yes I have shared

Comment: @gaurav singh yes i did

Comment: Code should be inside the question as "Code Sample".

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4496336/nextval-jdbc-insert-problem

Comment: @gaurav singh yes I am inserting correctly but I need the id which we inserted

Comment: The insertion doesn't generate an ID. What generates an ID is the query to the sequence. So, execute the query to get the next sequence number first. Then pass the value you get as aparameter to a second query, inserting the data.